# How to add Firepad to a reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add Firepad to a reactjs application. Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import firebase from "firebase";
import Firepad from "firepad";
import CodeMirror from 'codemirror';

class CourseNotes extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var firepadRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var codeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('firepad'), { lineWrapping: true });
    var firepad = Firepad.fromCodeMirror(firepadRef, codeMirror, {
            richTextShortcuts: true,
            richTextToolbar: true,
            defaultText: 'Hello, World!'
          });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>testing </div>
        <div id="firepad" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CourseNotes;
```

I've tried a few things to no success. Other solutions on stack overflow include adding these script tags to the html but that didn't seem to work.

```
<!-- CodeMirror -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.17.0/codemirror.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.17.0/codemirror.css" />

<!-- Firepad -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firepad/1.4.0/firepad.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firepad/1.4.0/firepad.min.js"></script>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the result? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I get this warning 
./~/firepad/dist/firepad.min.js
14:3292-3299 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

The other error in the chrome console:

Uncaught TypeError: place is not a function
    at new Display (codemirror.js:184)
    at new CodeMirror (codemirror.js:75)ere is this error

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes accross this question. I eventually figured it out.

The issue was the way create-react-app builds itself.

To use imported scripts just prepend "window." before the firebase and codemirror functions. IE:

var codeMirror = window.CodeMirror(document.getElementById('firepad'), { lineWrapping: true });

Answer (score 0):

Use these `npm packages` - `brace`, `react-ace`, `firebase`, `firepad`.

Since `firepad` needs `ace`to be present globally, assign brace to global var
like(not the best way, but works) before importing `firepad`

```
import brace from 'brace';
global.ace = brace;
global.ace.require = global.ace.acequire;
import Firepad from 'firepad';
```

Use `ref` to get instance of `ReactAce` and initialize it in `componentDidMount` using:

```
new Firepad.fromACE(this.firepadRef, this.aceInstance.editor, options);
```

Similarly for `CodeMirror` editor.

Hoping, this would be of some help.